# Visual Studio 2019 Community does not stop at breakpoints when debugging

Tags: visual-studio

I am building a visual basic application in VS 2019 community edition.  The application works but I want to add some additional functionality.  When I set a breakpoint and run the application, the application starts, executes, and ends without ever stopping at the breakpoint.  This is a screenshot of VS2019:

[image]

I tried closing VS2019 and opening it again.  I tried opening VS2019 as an administrator.  Neither resolved the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you %100 sure that you have not disabled break-points?

Answer (score 0):

Click in "Project" -> "Project Properties". In the "Compilation" section, disable the "Optimize code" option. Then the breakpoints will work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can set the Enable Optimizations to checked but you must make sure the Generate Debug Info is not set to none.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Switch your program from Release to Debug, and it should work.